# Why do the recycler items disappear when the search box is empty?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter

I created a to do list app, when I add some tasks, they are displayed correctly in Recycler.
Now, after adding the tasks, I want to search.
When I fill the search box with characters, it searches the tasks correctly, but as soon as the search box is empty (its length becomes zero), all the previously existing lists cannot be displayed, but if they exist in the database

AdapterClass

```java
// To set the list of tasks class inside the adapter to display the tasks
public void setTask(List<TaskModel> task) {
    this.taskModel = task;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

SQLiteDataBaseClass

```java
// This method is the search command inside the SQLite class
public List<TaskModel> searchBox(String query) {
    List<TaskModel> taskModel = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TASK + " WHERE title LIKE '%" + query + "%'", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TaskModel task = new TaskModel();
            task.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setCompleted(cursor.getInt(2) == 1);
            taskModel.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return taskModel;
}

// Method to return list of tasks in SQLite class
public List<TaskModel> getTask() {
    List<TaskModel> taskModel = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TASK, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TaskModel task = new TaskModel();
            task.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setCompleted(cursor.getInt(2) == 1);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return taskModel;
}
```

MainActivity

```java
public void setSearchBox() {
    searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                List<TaskModel> task = sqLite.searchBox(s.toString());
                adapter.setTask(task);
            } else {
                List<TaskModel> task = sqLite.getTask();
                adapter.setTask(task);
            }
        }
       
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you get `List<TaskModel>` on `onTextChanged`  else part when you removed search text from `EditText`?

Comment: When the length of the text is zero, you are invoking getTask. Are you sure it returns something always?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, I am sure and I used the text elsewhere and it works correctly

Comment: @Harshali Exactly when the `EditText` is empty, the list also disappears, but there is a gap in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your code closely I found one issue in `getTask()` method. You didn't added data fetched from database in list `taskModel` `List<TaskModel>` and you pass empty list to the adapter that's why you have data in database but not showing in `RecyclerView`.

Update `getTask()` method to this:

```java
// Method to return list of tasks in SQLite class
public List<TaskModel> getTask() {
    List<TaskModel> taskModel = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TASK, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TaskModel task = new TaskModel();
            task.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setCompleted(cursor.getInt(2) == 1);
            taskModel.add(task);  // <<--- ADD THIS LINE 
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return taskModel;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, it was completely correct.
In the method, a list that was not assigned a value is returned !